# PDL/perldl mac weird permissions/malware errors

Tags: perl, pdl

after a system update to Mac OS 10.15.4, when I try to execute perldl, I get popup messages that are unfamiliar, and when I google them, I get no results... That seems very odd.

The first message is:

> “Gnu.bundle” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified. macOS cannot verify that this app is free from malware. Chrome downloaded this file on March 3, 2019 from github.com.

I can 'move to trash' or 'cancel'. When I click cancel, I get another one:

> “IO.bundle” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified. macOS cannot verify that this app is free from malware. Chrome downloaded this file on March 3, 2019 from github.com.

In the terminal, I see the following when I first enter perldl:

```
> perldl
perlDL shell v1.357
 PDL comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. For details, see the file
 'COPYING' in the PDL distribution. This is free software and you
 are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions, see
 the same file for details.
```

After I click cancel to the system popups, I see the following, and it exits:

```
ReadLines  enabled
Cannot do `initialize' in Term::ReadLine::Gnu at /Applications/PDL/bin/perldl line 232.
```

This worked before the update... Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is better addressed on StackExchange's Ask Different. That said, [this Apple document] (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491) should help.

Comment: It looks like MacOSX Catalina **security feature** require your permission to run third party software.  You need to check 'Security &  Privacy' settings for `perldl` permission to run on the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Summarising the comments from JRFerguson and Polar Bear (feel free to answer instead and comment on this, and I will delete this):

What the OP was seeing was caused by the then-new Gatekeeper feature of MacOS (see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491), which rejected the libraries they were trying to load since they were not cryptographically signed in a way recognised by that feature.